# Nutch deployment on hadoop will not index to solr

Tags: apache, solr, nutch, oozie, hue

I have oozie workflow that does a nutch crawl I designed using hue.

All steps in the process work, except for indexing to solr.

The oozie action that defines the solrindex is as follows

`

```
<start to="solr-test"/>
    <action name="solr-test">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <main-class>org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob</main-class>
            <java-opts>solr.server.url=http://ip-redacted:8983/solr/raw</java-opts>
            <arg>hdfs://ip-redacted:8020/user/admin/c</arg>
            <arg>-dir</arg>
            <arg>hdfs://ip-redacted:8020/user/admin/s000</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
```

`

When I run the action I get the following error message

```
Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], exit code [-1]
```

The locations `hdfs://ip-redacted:8020/user/admin/c` and 
`hdfs://ip-redacted:8020/user/admin/s000` are locations that contain the crawldb and the segments respectively.

The stderr of the job says ::

```
`Log Length: 122
Intercepting System.exit(-1)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], exit code [-1]`
```

The syslog says::

```
`ERROR [main] org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob: Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriter not found.
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.<init>(IndexWriters.java:51)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:100)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:195)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:55)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:38)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:225)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)`
```

have verified that the class exists in the apache-nutch-1.7.jar file.

And if I request hadoop to run as a map-reduce job in the command shell as follows::

```
`hadoop jar apache-nutch-1.7.jar org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob -D solr.server.url=http://ip-redacted:8983/solr/raw hdfs://ip-redacted:8020/user/admin/c -dir hdfs://ip-redacted:8020/user/admin/s000`
```

It works!! But, when I do it as a oozie job, created through Hue, it fails...

Also, other actions, like inject, generate, fetch, parse work fine in Hue. It's only solrindex step that fails and I don't know what to do to fix it. Any input on this will be great!

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the Nutch jar (and dependencies if needed) in a 'lib' directory in the HDFS workspace of the workflow?

Comment: I tried doing that. But every time the workflow starts execution, all files in the lib directory get deleted, and the apache-nutch-1.7.jar get's copied into lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I'm beginning to loathe the packaging of Nutch!

Try extracting the classes/plugins folder from the job archive, copy it to HDFS (something like  hdfs dfs -put -r plugins lib) and then add the HDFS path of the plugins folder to the "files" list of the indexing step.

Best,
Edoardo